# Passcode permutation problem

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

James has a mobile phone which allows him to set a password consisting of 5 characters. The characters are to be chosen from the list {2,4,6,8,A,B,C,D,E}.

James has forgotten his password. However, he is certain that he used 3 distinct digits and 2 distinct letters. He attempts to recall the password. Find the maximum number of failed possible attempts he needs to make before he can recall the password correctly.

My answer:

$$\binom{4}{3}\times3! \times \binom{5}{2}\times2! = 480$$

The correct answer is 4799. WHat have I done incorrectly? Thanks

Comment: meaning 4permutate 3- 5 permutate 2. Did I type incorrectly ?

Comment: edited. sorry mistake

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to choose the positions of the three digits, which can be done in $\binom{5}{3}$ ways.

There are $\binom{5}{3}$ ways to choose the positions of the three digits, $\binom{4}{3}$ ways to select three of the four digits, $3!$ ways to arrange the selected digits in the three places reserved for digits, $\binom{5}{2}$ ways to select two of the five letters, and $2!$ ways to arrange the letters in the two remaining positions.  Therefore, there are
$$\binom{5}{3}\binom{4}{3}3!\binom{5}{2}2!$$
passcodes with three digits and two letters, only one of which is correct.  Hence, in the worst case scenario, James can enter
$$\binom{5}{3}\binom{4}{3}3!\binom{5}{2}2! - 1$$
passcodes with three digits and two letters before entering the right passcode.

Comment: thany you very much. I got it now.